# Application should show prime numbers and start from last shown figure. How to proceed?

Tags: java, android

Would bee glad if someone could help me out with some minor issues.

I want my application to show the user when a prime number has been detected.
Right now the app only shows the last primenumber depending on the conditons in the while-loop. It would be nice if the primenumber where enumerated every 0.5 second or so.

I tried using thread.sleep but the application does not work normaly. 
When the app is closed and then restarted, I would like the count to proceed from the last prime number.

Any ides folks?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    generateOddNumber(1);
}

private boolean isPrime(long candidate) {
    long sqrt = (long) Math.sqrt(candidate);
        for (long i = 3; i <= sqrt; i += 2) 
        if (candidate % i == 0) return false;
        return true;
}

public void saveInfo(long prime) {
    sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("PrimeNumbers", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putLong("Number", prime);
    editor.apply();
}

public void getData() {
    sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("PrimeNumbers", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    long nr = sharedPref.getLong("Number", 0);
}

public void generateOddNumber(long x) {
    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    while (x < 1000) {
        if (isPrime(x) == true) {
            saveInfo(x);
            myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(x));
            try { Thread.sleep(1000);}
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        x = x + 2;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u are ready saving the last prime number into a shared preference. so before calling "generateOddNumber(1)" u just need to get the prime number u saved.

try this. hope this will work

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("PrimeNumbers", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
long nr = sharedPref.getLong("Number", 1);
generateOddNumber(nr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to deal with that in your onCreate and onStop methods. First try to understand these callbacks. You can read more here [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html). When your app is stops you need to save and when its restored back load whatever you want.

And why do you need to pause the current thread each time.

```
try { Thread.sleep(1000);}
```

Here you can find explanation and sample code for usifg [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: I would like the application to show the primenumber for the user, for a while. Something like 1 and then 3 and then  7 etc.. How shoudl I proceed?

Comment: you can use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). I explained in the answer the Steps you need to go through. You need to spend some time reading the Docs and understand it. Anyway, In the onCreate start your task to generate your numbers and populate the ui. When the app is terminating save the number in the onSstop(). You can read it back in the onCreat()